# Principio REST del metodo PUT en Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, api, rest, http

Estoy elaborando un API REST tipo CRUD común y corriente con el modelo `users` que trae laravel por defecto

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;

class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail {

  use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable, CanResetPassword;

  /**
   * The attributes that are mass assignable.
   *
   * @var string[]
   */
  protected $fillable = [
      'name',
      'email',
      'password'
  ];

  /**
   * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $hidden = [
      'password',
      'remember_token',
  ];

  /**
   * The attributes that should be cast.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $casts = [
      'email_verified_at' => 'datetime'
  ];
}
```

y las rutas las genero con `Route::apiResource`

```
Route::apiResource('users', UserController);
```

dado que quiero encontrar el usuario por el `email` o el `id` hago un enlace o inyección explicita del parámetro de la ruta en el `RouteServiceProvider` dentro del método `boot` con `Route::bind`

```
Route::bind('user', function($userId){

  $user = User::where(fn($query) => $query->where('id', $userId)->orWhere('email', $userId))->first();
  if(request()->method() === 'PUT') return $user;
  return $userId;
});
```

Aquí es donde entra el tema principal, este método (`Route::bind()`) debe retornar la instancia de una clase, si no, retornara una  `ExceptionModelNotFound 404 - not found`, pero me gustaría poder recibir el `null` en mi controlador y así validar yo dependiendo del método (PUT o PATCH) si crear el nuevo registro (cosa de que según principios REST debe poder hacer un recurso si no existe una coincidencia) o simplemente actualizar uno existente.

Mi método `update` de `UserController` es el siguiente

```
public function update(Request $request, User $user){

  $input = $request->all();
  $method = $request->method();
  if($method === 'PUT') $request->validate($this->rules);

  $update = [
    'PUT' => fn() => ($user) ? $user->update($input) : $user = $user::create($input),
    'PATCH' => function() use($user, $input){

      foreach ($input as $key => $val){
        $user->$key = (!empty($val)) ? $val : $user->$key;
      }
      $user->save();
      return $user;
    }
  ];
  return response()->json($update[$method]());
}
```

Anteriormente lo tenia sin inyección de modelos y el método `ùpdate` funcionaba, algo como esto

```
public function update(Request $request, $user){
```

Pero debido a la inyección explicita esto ya no me toma el parámetro, ademas de que solo me interesa este comportamiento al actualizar ya que esta en el resto de métodos ayuda en la reducción de código y esta bien manejar el 404 - Not found.
No se si estoy fallando en algo o quizá laravel proporciona una mejor forma de hacerlo la cual desconozco.

Gracias de antemano.

PD: El código esta un poco abstraído, se ve un poco desordenado porque trate de simplificarlo.